# IBM System X 3755 Opteron

Tags: ibm, opteron

is there somewhere a list of all the supported CPUs for System x server? I own the configuration system x3755 8877-4RG. Original 8218 Opterons (dual-core) are installed. Can these CPUs be replaced by e.g. some quad core opterons 83xx?
many thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Most people would look up the [vendor documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/ShowDoc.wss?docURL=/common/ssi/rep_sm/1/877/ENUS8877-_h01/index.html&lang=en&request_locale=en) and find something like the supported hardware:

> AMD **dual-core** 8000 Series Opteron processors

not quad core and

> Microprocessor Upgrades:
>
> ```
>  Dual Core Opteron** Processor Model 8212                     40K1200  
>  Dual Core Opteron** Processor Model 8214                     40K1201  
>  Dual Core Opteron** Processor Model 8218                     40K1202  
>  Dual Core Opteron** Processor Model 8220  SE                 40K1203
> ```

But with a system that hasn't been sold as new for the past 7 years you probably don't care about vendor support anymore.

Then a quick look at the CPU specs show that despite using the same CPU socket the [8200 series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_Opteron_microprocessors#Opteron_8200-series_.22Santa_Rosa.22_.2890_nm.29) run at a higher CPU voltage than the [8300 series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_Opteron_microprocessors#Opteron_8300-series_.22Barcelona.22_.2865_nm.29) and my assumption is that it is unlikely that the server motherboard will automatically adjust for that...

When your system is already 7 years old, why invest in it? With new hardware you can get 32 cores in a dual CPU system, supporting more memory and lower power consumption.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It's just a hobby, and although I have also searched the documentation I have not found. Unfortunately, I did not know that there is such a general documentation. Thanks again